# Why are you not able to modify the OS kernel code while its running?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I know you can download the Kernel code and modify from there but why is it that we can't edit the Kernel while its running on a system?

Comment: You can on most systems.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you could edit the kernel in-place by modifying its memory, and this is how [some exploits](https://tc.gtisc.gatech.edu/bss/2014/r/kernel-exploits.pdf) work. However, modifying the kernel in-memory is very likely to cause system instability.

You can load and unload portions of the kernel ([known as modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module)) using `modprobe` or possibly use [kexec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) to load a new new kernel that you or some one else has compiled.